# How can i stop divs from overlapping in a responsive web page

Tags: html, css

i need to stop my divs from overlapping in my responsive web page when i make the page smaller.
How could i do this?
I have tried to look for solutions but i have not found anything yet.

HTML:

```
<div class="pagepicturecontainer">
            <div>
                <div class="image_box1" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike1tl.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image_box2" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike2tm.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image_box3" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike3tr.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image_box4" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike4bl.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image_box5" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike5bm.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image_box6" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike6br.jpg"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
`.image_box1 {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: none;
  float: left;
}

.image_box2 {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: none;
  float: left;
}

.image_box3 {
 width: 33%;
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
}

.image_box4 {
 width: 33%;
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
}

.image_box5 {
 width: 33%;
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
}

.image_box6 {
 width: 33%;
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width:412px;
 max-height:523px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}

.pagepicturecontainer{
    margin-left: 190px;
}`
```

I have read other answers but their code seems different to mine.
I am a beginner at HTML CSS.

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself. First try to understand how to use "class" properly. You're not ready for responsive!

Comment: The code above was given to me here on this website on my previous post, i understand class perfectly.

Comment: If you understood class then you would understand that you could replace all of your current classes with a single class because they all have the same attributes.

Comment: Take the images out, put borders around the divs (using css) and see if the behaviour matches your expectations. You may find that it's the images causing the problem, not the divs.

Comment: @geoidesic i know i could do that but i am planning to have these pictures on more than 1 page & each will have their own border with a different color around them.

Comment: Add the borders and you'll see the problem

Comment: Did none of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

The divs are not overlapping. It's just that your image size stays the same while your divs shrink, so the images end up looking like they are overlapping.

Try this instead:

HTML

```
<div class="pagepicturecontainer">
        <div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike1tl.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike2tm.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike3tr.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike4bl.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike5bm.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image_box" > <a href="riders.html"> <img src="./img/bike6br.jpg"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image_box {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: none;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
 max-width:412px;
 max-height:523px;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}

.pagepicturecontainer{
    margin-left: 190px;
}
```

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/geoidesic/full/VXJNRN/

Comment: Tried this, image stays the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a width of 33% means that all the `divs` surrounding the `image_box` will be 33% of the parent `div` which is the first inner `div`. Remove the first inner `div`.

Secondly setting `max-width` for the images means they feel any space available and possibly go beyond the parent `div` , if the image is bigger than the parent div.

This happens when you shrink the page. Since the `image_box` will take 33% of the current parent `div` size. So the smaller the page, the smaller the `div` gets but the image won't decrease in size because of its max-width.

Using flexbox can solve this. As shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
<style>
.image_box {
  background-color: none;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.pagepicturecontainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style>
    <body>
    <div class="pagepicturecontainer">
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image_box">
                <a href="riders.html">
                    <img src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[Check this if you are new to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/)

[and this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)